# How to cite the place of a conference in Chicago manual of style?

Tags: citations, chicago-manual-of-style

I am confused about what should I add in the place of conference in the Chicago manual of style?

Place of the publisher or the location of the conference?

I just want to cite the conference paper. For a conference paper in the ACM website, for example [this one](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3217881), it is published in New York, but the conference is held in Tempe. I do not know which one I should use in the bibliography in the CMOS format.

Comment: Nice that the citation is pretty much there at the link.  You just have to shorten it and put the order in however CMOS wants.  Definitely Tempe.  I would say "ACM Digital Library" as the publisher and the location as "dl.acm.org" not New York.  Though if you have space, it would be better to give the location as the full version, "https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3217881"  If it were a paper book you were citing, then the physical location of the publisher makes sense to use (in addition to the location of the conference, which is necessary).

Comment: Okay, I found a great source and turned this into an answer.  I wasn't aware of DOI citing (didn't exist when I was in grad school) but otherwise, I had it right.

Answer (score 2):

Author of  Paper, A., and B. Author of Paper. Year. "Title of Paper." Paper presented at Title of Conference: Subtitle of Conference, Location, Date. https://doi.org/10.XXX/XXXXX.XX

So in your case:

**Matt Baughman, Christian Haas, Rich Wolski, Ian Foster, and Kyle Chard.  2018,  "Predicting Amazon Spot Prices with LSTM Networks." Paper presented at 9th Workshop on Scientific Cloud Computing, Tempe, AZ, USA, June 11, 2018. https://doi.org/10.1145/3217880.3217881**

Source: [Murdoch University](https://libguides.murdoch.edu.au/Chicago/conference).

There are slightly different forms for papers without a DOI, papers in a print collection, and for citing the actual proceedings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your edit and answer. I find that website too. What I am confused is what is the "Place of publication" or "Location". The BibTex exported from the ACM website has two fields "address = {New York, NY, USA}" which is the address of the publisher, and "location = {Tempe, AZ, USA}" which is the location of the conference. In the examples in the [Murdoch University](https://libguides.murdoch.edu.au/Chicago/conference), the place of the publisher and location of the conference are the same.

Comment: In the correct citation template for the example you provided, there is no field for publication location.  The location field is just for the conference.  The other 3 templates do list "Place of publication."  Since "location" is also a field in those templates, it's clear that "location" refers to the conference itself.  But yeah, it's confusing.

Comment: @WZhao According to the BibTeX implementation, the entry type `inproceedings` doesn't have a field "location" (cf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX).